# How to show new item(update or add) in recycleview top in list

Tags: android, mysql, json

How to show new item(update or add) in

`recycleview` top in list

Comment: Be more specific what are you asking?

Comment: Rahul, I think the question is understood.. I agree it's not descriptive..

Answer (score 0):

In  update or add method add these 2 lines below:

```
mArrayList.add(0, item);
notifyItemInserted(0);
```

Where "item" is the object of mArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to add a new item at the top of the RecyclerView:

```
you_array_list.add(0, your_item);
notifyItemInserted(0);
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Hopefully this will work.